# angular ng-repeat with bootstrap list-inline

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

`<body ng-app="" ng-init="names=['james', 'sean', 'emmanuel']">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Angular ng-repeat demo</h2>
      <ul class="list-inline" ng-repeat="name in names">
        <li> {{ name }} </li>
      </ul>
    </div>`

I'm new to angular and bootstrap. The code above does not place the names on a single line. Any suggestion?
ps: list-line is a bootstrap css class

Comment: Why are you using `ul` and `li` if you want the names on the same line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ng-repeat` on the **li** element not the **ul**:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Angular ng-repeat demo</h2>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li ng-repeat="name in names"> {{ name }} </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```